# Help finding an eigen vector

Tags: linear-algebra

```
Find the eigen vectors of
```

[image]

I found $v=\left[1,2/3,1\right]$ and $\left[-1,0,1\right]$ but according to wolfram, there is one more, $\left[0,1,0\right]$, does anyone know how to get this eigenvector?

I found $\left[1,2/3,1\right]$ through the eigenvalue of $4$ and I found 
$\left[-1,0,1\right]$ through the eigenvalue of $-2$

Thanks

Comment: There is another eigenvector for eigenvalue of -2

Comment: How would one find that one?

Comment: @AA: How did you find the first one? The 2nd EV is another solution of the equation system that you have to solve to find the EVs

Comment: I found it with the eignvalue of 2 but Im still confused on how to find the last eigenvector

Comment: Hint: Find the kernel of the matrix A+2I, where A is the matrix in the question

Comment: Yes I definetly did that already to find the first eigenvector..

Comment: The second component, $ \ x_2 \ $ is a "free variable".  For your eigenvector, you set it to 0 .  For another one, set it to something else, say, 1 .

Comment: Hint: $x+0y+z=0$. $y$ can take any value and $z = -x$. Thus, the general solution is $(-x,y,x)$. Can you now see why the two eigenvectors are $(-1,0,1)$ and $(0,1,0)$?

Comment: But y must always be 0, how does that make sense

Comment: No, for $y$ you can chose whatever you want to get a solution.

Comment: Hmm, How? 
{{1,0,1},{0,1,0},{0,0,0}}.{x,y,z}=0 if we solve this then we get

x+z=0, y=0 which gives us the eigenvector {-1,0,1}

I still don't quite understand how that other eigen vector appeared

Comment: @AA: You want to find vectors $v$ such that $\begin{pmatrix}1+2 & 0 & 3 \\ 2 & -2+2 & 2 \\ 3 & 0 & 1+2 \end{pmatrix}v = 0$. The matrix has zeroes everywhere in the middle column; how can you possibly get an $1$ there while solving?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the eigenvectors to the eigenvalue $\lambda=-2$ you have to solve the system

$$\left(A-\lambda\mathcal I\right)\nu=0\tag 1$$

For $\lambda=-2$ this yiels to

$$\begin{pmatrix}3&0&3\\2&0&2\\3&0&3\end{pmatrix}\nu = 0 $$

which can be reduced to

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&0&1\end{pmatrix}\cdot \nu = 0$$

which has for example the non-trivial solutions
$\nu_1 = \left(1,0,-1\right)^T$ and $\nu_2=\left(0,1,0\right)^T$

Comment: Thanks but I dont understand the jump to the very last step. How did you find the eigenvectors?

Comment: @AA: Do you disagree that those two vectors are solutions?

Comment: You know that the eigenvector $v$ is that vector that has the property $\begin{pmatrix}3 & 0 & 3 \\ 2 & 0 & 2 \\ 3 & 0 & 3 \end{pmatrix} v = 0$ you see by multiplying the matrix for $v=(1,0,1)$ that the result is $0$ hence v is an eigenvector to the eigenvalue $-2$;)

Comment: @HenningMakholm It says on Wolfram that those are the solutions, I disagree with (0,1,0), I dont know where it comes from.

Comment: @AA just for the same reason that I've told you before if you take $v = (0,1,0)$ and you evaluate $\begin{pmatrix}3 & 0 & 3 \\ 2 & 0 & 2 \\ 3 & 0 & 3 \end{pmatrix} v$ you get $0$

Comment: @AA Try x=1, y=9, z=-1. Can you see that y can take ANY value?

Comment: Yes I see that reasoning but how would one discover that (0,1,0) is a possible answer?

Comment: The second eigenvector for $ \ \lambda \ = \ -2 \ $ must be linearly independent of the first one.  Setting $ \ x = z = 0 \ $ with $ \ y \ $ being anything non-zero guarantees that.

Comment: I do not see that y can take any value, that does not make any sense to me. y should be always 0 to the last step above. It can be translated to:
x+z=0
y=0

So y must always be 0, right?

Comment: @AA: WHY do you think $y$ should always be $0$? The equation is that $x+0y+z=0$, so no matter what $y$ is, it's going to disappear when you multiply with $0$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm There is also the equation y=0 which states the y is 0. I don't quite understand the logic here.

Comment: No. You need to solve the linear system of equation $\begin{pmatrix}3 & 0 & 3 \\ 2 & 0 & 2 \\ 3 & 0 & 3 \end{pmatrix} v = \begin{pmatrix} 0\\0\\0 \end{pmatrix}$ this system has two linear independently solution which can be found (if you don't see them right away, with the gaussian algorithms ;)

Comment: @AA: No, there's no such equation. Where do you think such an equation comes from?

Comment: The equation which states the condition among the variables is $ \ 1 \cdot x \ + \ 0 \cdot y \ + \ 1 \cdot z \ = \ 0 \ $ .  With the first and third variables equal to zero, the second may have _any_ value.

Comment: If you take the vector of the example ($(0,1,0)$) you get $1 \dot {} 0 + 0 \dot {} 1 + 1 \dot{} 0 = 0$

Comment: I found that I made a calculation error when calculating [A-(lambda)I]V=0. I am slamming my head against my desk now

Comment: Thank you for the support guys, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You want to solve the equation
$$ \begin{pmatrix}3&0&3\\2&0&2\\3&0&3\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$$

Doing Gaussian elimination on this produces:
$$ \begin{pmatrix}1&0&1\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$$

A general procedure for finding the solution from the reduced row echelon form is:

> The variables that correspond to columns that do NOT contain a pivot element can be arbitrary. Once you have selected their values, each *row* with a pivot element tells you what the variable corresponding to the *column* of the pivot should be.

Here the only pivot element is the $1$ in the upper left corner, so the values of $y$ and $z$ can be whatever we want, and to find the value of $x$ we write down the equation of the first line
$$ x+0y+z=0 \implies x = -z $$

So the *general* solution of the equiation is: All vectors of the form $(-z,y,z)$ for arbitrary $y$ and $z$.

To find a basis for the solution space, we can set each of the independent variables to $1$ one at a time.

Setting $y=1$ and keeping $z$ at $0$ gives $(-z,y,z)=(0,1,0)$.

Setting $z=1$ and keeping $y$ at $0$ gives $(-z,y,z)=(-1,0,1)$.

These are your two eigenvectors (except for the sign of the second one, but you can always multiply an eigenvector by a nonzero constant such as $-1$ to get another eigenvector).